# Using hook_node_presave to auto-select a reference field from a field list selection

Tags: theming, hooks

I'm trying to use hook_node_presave to select a value in a term reference field based on a selection a user makes in a field list field. The term reference field is hidden from the user. The code I'm working with is problemmatic in at least two ways:

1) I'm not sure I'm referencing the correct theme in my function header because the dpm() is not outputting anything. But it's in the administrative theme 'seven' that this form is running so I assume that's right.

2) I'm getting errors when I run this code saying 'syntax error, unexpected ||' wherever I have those. Am I not using the correct syntax for OR operators? It seems fine to me. I tried OR in place of || and got the same errors.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
function seven_node_presave($node) {
    $field_type = $form['field_type']['und']['#options'];
    dpm($field_type);
    if (($field_type == 4) || ($field_type == 5)) || ($field_type == 7) || 
($field_type == 6)) {
        $form['field_icon']['und']['#options'][]= '2';
    }
    elseif (($field_type == '9') || ($field_type == '98')) || ($field_type == '8')) {
        $form['field_icon']['und']['#options'][]= '6';
    }
    elseif (($field_type == '3') || ($field_type == '1')) || ($field_type == '2')) {
        $form['field_icon']['und']['#options'][]= '1';
    }
}
```

Note 1: the numbers being compared to (ex: $field_type == 4) are the 'keys' for those fields, not the actual text the user would select.

Note 2: I'm running this from a module called grouphideandselect, not from template.php...maybe that's my problem?

Comment: What do you mean "it's in the administrative theme 'seven'" yet "I'm running this from a module"?  Where is the code located?  How are you expecting it to be called?

Comment: @Darvanen I mean my code is in a custom module I created but the form I'm using to input the content type is using the Seven theme. When a user fills out the form and submits it I want the code above to run and auto-fill a taxonomy term field based on a selection in a field list.

Comment: Please don't add an answer in the question. Thank you.

Comment: @kiamlaluno ok but why did you remove it? now i can't add it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Darvanen said above, the function name is wrong, replace HOOK by the module's name in HOOK_node_presave().
About the || operators, you could use in_array instead or a single associative array:

```
function grouphideandselect_node_presave($node) {
    $field_type = $form['field_type']['und']['#options'];
    dpm($field_type);

    $field_type_to_icon = array(
      1 => 1,
      2 => 1,
      3 => 1,
      4 => 2,
      5 => 2,
      7 => 2,
      8 => 6,
      9 => 6,
      98 => 6,
    );

    if (isset($field_type_to_icon[$field_type])) {
      $form['field_icon']['und']['#options'][] = $field_type_to_icon[$field_type];
    }
}
```

EDIT: from another question of yours I see that you already tried renaming the function to `grouphideandselect_node_presave`. You need to make sure that:
- the function's name is right
- the module is enabled
- you cleared Drupal's cache afterwards

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. Is this the correct way to set a term reference field programmatically (the field_icon field is a term reference field)? I feel like maybe it requires some additional preloading of the terms or something since the vocabulary and associated keys are in another table in the database.

Comment: Yes it's correct but the full solution involves setting the field_icon value on the node itself (see Darvanen's answer for more details).
You could load the vocabulary and loop through the tree instead of having that hard-coded table to translate types to icons. At the end of the day, it's still a `presave` with `$node->field_icon[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'] = something`.

Comment: thanks for your help. I added my final working code to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Ben's answer is correct on getting the code to fire, regarding your OR operators, they're fine, it's the syntax you're using around them that is the problem: you have too many parentheses, or not enough.

Let's look at one of the lines:

```
elseif (($field_type == '9') || ($field_type == '98')) || ($field_type == '8')) {
```

After `elseif` you open two parentheses, fine. You close one after your first comparison, open one, close two.  Now you've closed all of the parentheses but you're still adding more criteria.

It might be easier to see if you remove the unnecessary parentheses around each comparison:

```
elseif ($field_type == '9' || $field_type == '98') || $field_type == '8') {
```

Everything after `elseif` needs to be in one set of parentheses, and then you either have a single command (bad practice) or a code block in brackets `{}` (good practice).  So you need to either, add one more parenthesis at the very beginning, or remove the one in the middle.  I suspect you're after the latter which would look like this:

```
elseif ($field_type == '9' || $field_type == '98' || $field_type == '8') {
```

---

As for your question in comments:

> "Is this the correct way to set a term reference field programmatically (the field_icon field is a term reference field)?"

The method looks ok to me, that is using a presave function to adjust values is fine.  But you need to edit the `$node` variable that is being acted upon or you will not achieve anything, because the code that called the hook is not interested in the form, only the node.

I would use dpm($node) to discover how the node is structured and then adjust those values in your code.